# Make copy-pasted Skype chats use local date formats

Tags: windows-7, skype

My laptop is running Windows 7 and Skype 5.1.0.112, and is set to the "Australia" locale.  This means that dates (e.g. the clock on the task bar) are shown in this format:

DD/MM/YYYY

However, when I copy-paste Skype chats where more than one person speaks, each person's comment is preceded by a date time in American format, that is:

MM/DD/YYYY

Is there some way to get it to use my Windows setting for this?  I have a feeling older versions did, but maybe I'm just using rose-coloured glasses...